# How to make an image smaller after every click?

Tags: javascript, html, image-resizing

I figured out how to change the size of the image after one click but I am trying to make the image shrink by a few pixels after every click, I looked all over this site and other sites but I have found nothing that refers to how change the size after each click. I am looking for a way strictly in this format, I am looking for code that is able to work within an HTML file.

Thanks everyone for your input, all of your suggestions work fine for me. Thanks again to everyone who is commenting and sending answers.

The code below is what I have so far

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
                <head> 
                    <script>
                    "use script";
                    function resizeImage(img) 
                    {
                      img.style.width = "150px";
                      img.style.height = "150px";
                    }

                    </script>

                </head>
                <body>   
                    <figure id="image-box">

                      <img src="img/green.jpg" alt= "Whoops" style="width:200px;height:200px;" class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">

                    </figure>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Instead of changing the width/height to a fixed number, change them to a percentage of their current size

Comment: What exactly is a "Pure Javascript code?" Javascript can be either in a `.js` file called with a script tag or within a script tag itself... it makes no difference.

Comment: `img.style.width = parseInt(img.style.width || '150') * .7 + "px";`, then repeat for `height`. Basically, read the `width`, if its not defined yet (akla you havent set `style.width` yet yourself), set it to `150`. Then multiply that value by the scale (`.7` which is `70%`). Next time, get the previous value, make it smaller, and apply. And so on.

Comment: What does `I am not looking for code that is able to work within an HTML file.` mean?

Comment: somethinghere, Thanks for your help, I hope anybody else who has the same problem is able to find this. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Also I think you mean "use strict" and not "use script"

Answer (score 3):

Just parseInt the computed style:

```js
function resizeImage(img) {
  var style = getComputedStyle(img,null),w=style.width,h=style.height;
  w = parseInt(w)*.9; // or whatever your modifier is 
  h = parseInt(h)*.9; // parseInt removes the traling "px" so
  img.style.width  = w+"px"; // we need to append the "px" 
  img.style.height = h+"px";
}
```

```css
.image-slide { width:200px;height:200px; }
```

```html
<figure id="image-box">

  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200?text=Whoops" alt="Whoops" 
   class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">

</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

By combining some basic JS ideas you can easily do this:

```js
var scale = .9;

document.querySelector( 'img' ).addEventListener( 'click', function(){
  
  // Get the width and height calculated in the viewport
  
  var { width, height } = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // Apply by multiplying it by style, 
  // which will result in an update to the above 
  // boundingClientRect next time

  event.target.style.width = width * scale + 'px';
  event.target.style.height = height * scale + 'px';
  
});
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
```

Comment: Any idea how getComputedStyle and getBoundingClientRect differ in actual use?

Comment: @mplungjan `getBoundingClientRect` is actually less about the `width` and `height` but more about the current relation of the element with the `viewport`, usually they will match up. But I think it uses less code to get the _actual_ `width` and `height` of an element. And they're already numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`img.style.width` will work only if that style is set inline in the HTML; it will not return anything if the size comes from a CSS rule or from the image's natural size.  `getComputedStyle()` is a better option, but `getClientBoundingRect()` has the advantage that it returns numbers, so you don't have to fiddle around removing the units "px" before doing the math:

```js
function resizeImage(img) {
  let rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
  img.style.width = rect.width - 10 + "px";
  img.style.height = rect.height - 10 + "px";
}
```

```html
<figure id="image-box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" onclick="resizeImage(this)">
</figure>
```

Comment: Cool cool, matches up nicely. I wonder though, is it technically better to just call it once and get both variables out? Mostly because I feel like this is an otherwise expensive operation? But correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: I haven't done a performance test, but I believe the only expensive part of this is the document reflow, which will only happen after the function completes anyway -- so it doesn't matter whether you assign w+h simultaneously or in separate lines of code.   (Corrections welcome if I'm wrong about that, though!)

Comment: Like you i havent done the test :) i always imagine it just calculating it in the background, but could be wrong. Our answers are pretty close :)

Comment: I guess you're right that I don't need to be calling getBoundingClientRect() twice; I've edited the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code, might not be perfect, but it does the job

```js
function resizeImage(img) {
      img.style.width = parseInt(img.style.width.replace('px','')) - 10 + 'px';
      img.style.height = parseInt(img.style.height.replace('px','')) - 10 + 'px';
    }
```

```html
<figure id="image-box">

  <img src="http://www.tascsoftware.co.uk/wiki/PARS_Connect/images/0/0e/Green.jpg" alt="Whoops" style="width:200px;height:200px;" class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">
  
</figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```html
<!doctype html>
            <html>
                <head> 
                    <script>
                    "use script";
                    function resizeImage(img) 
                    {
          
                var height = parseFloat(img.style.width);;
   var width = parseFloat(img.style.width);;

                      img.style.width =  (height - 10) + "px";
                      img.style.height = (width - 10) + "px";
                    }

                    </script>

                </head>
                <body>   
                    <figure id="image-box">

                      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt= "Whoops" style="width:200px;height:200px;" class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">

                    </figure>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: "*Are you trying this:*" - answers are for answers, not requests for clarification

Comment: Where are you getting the `width` and `height` variable from anyway?

Comment: Sorry, @SamSwift웃 I have changed. Thanks for correcting

Comment: @somethinghere actually it was hidden inside the snippet. I haven't noticed. thanks for correcting :)

Comment: What if I define my height in `%`? You method is _too_ specific, assuming certain string properties. One property you can be sure of it has to start with a number, so just use a `parseFloat` to be safer?

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for letting me know. I have changed it